# When calculating the domain of $f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+\log_2(x^2-1))$...

Tags: calculus

$f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+\log_2(x^2-1))$.

I wrote:$\text{dom} f = {x> \pm 1 \land x \neq \pm \sqrt{2^{\frac{k}{\pi}} -1}}$ with $x \neq \pm \sqrt{2^{\frac{k}{\pi}} -1}$ being the domain for $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}+\log_2(x^2-1))$.

I tried to plug some value for $k$ to see if the domain was consistent with the graph drawn by Geogebra but it was wrong.

I tried to ask wolfram alpha for help and it told me that the domain was: $\text{dom} f = \{x> \pm 1 \land \frac{\log_2(x^2+1)}{\pi} \neq k\}$, which is consistent with the graph drawn by Geogebra.

I thought that my calculation was equivalent:
$\frac{\pi}{2}+\log_2(x^2-1) \neq \frac{\pi}{2} +k\pi$
$\log_2(x^2-1) \neq k\pi$
$x^2-1 \neq 2^{k\pi}$
$x^2 \neq 2^{k\pi}+1$
$x \neq \sqrt{ 2^{k\pi}+1}$.

Comment: Did Wolfram Alpha really write $x>\pm 1$? To me, this notation is meaningless:if it is supposed to mean "$x>-1$ or $x>1$", then one would better write $x>-1$; if it is "$x>-1$ and $x>1$", then it is simpler to write $x>1$. $\log_2(x^2-1)$ is defined if and only if $x<-1$ and $x>1$.

Comment: Saying "$x>±1$" is not quite correct and should be something like $|x|>1$.  Meanwhile you seem to change the sign in $\log_2(x^2-1)$ to  $\log_2(x^2+1)$.

Comment: A nitpick - try avoiding the use of logical operators unless your question is about logic. The result isn't pretty.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have confused $2^{k/\pi}$ (in your answer) with $2^{k\pi}$ (in your calculation).